# polymer core-header-panel height issue

Tags: polymer

Why are these two snippets different?
The first snippet works as expected
The second is just a copy of the contents of the body tag placed into a custom element called my-header and my-header is inserted into the body tag

The second one is not honoring the height  of the body tag using fullbleed layout vertical.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
    <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
</head>

<body fullbleed layout vertical>

<core-header-panel flex>
    <core-toolbar>
        <div>Hello World!</div>
    </core-toolbar>
    <div class="content">Content goes here...</div>
</core-header-panel>

</body>

</html>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
    <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
    <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
    <polymer-element name="my-header" attributes="">
        <template>
            <style>
            </style>
            <core-header-panel flex>
                <core-toolbar>
                    <div>Hello World!</div>
                </core-toolbar>
                <div class="content">Content goes here...</div>
            </core-header-panel>
        </template>
        <script>
            (function () {

                Polymer({
                    // define element prototype here
                });

            })();
        </script>
    </polymer-element>
</head>
<body fullbleed layout vertical>
<my-header></my-header>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the height to your element and core-header-panel

```
  <style>
    :host, core-header-panel {
      height: 100%;
    }
  </style>
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-header-panel/core-header-panel.html">
  <link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-toolbar/core-toolbar.html">
  <polymer-element name="my-header">

    <template>
      <style>
        :host,
        core-header-panel {
          height: 100%;
        }
      </style>

      <core-header-panel flex>
        <core-toolbar>
          <div>Hello World!</div>
        </core-toolbar>
        <div class="content">Content goes here...</div>
      </core-header-panel>

    </template>

    <script>
      (function() {

        Polymer({
          // define element prototype here
        });

      })();
    </script>
  </polymer-element>
</head>

<body fullbleed layout vertical>

  <my-header></my-header>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank, I knew the header element needed a height as it states in the docs, and I had tried that, but I forgot to use :host as the target.